# Rearrange numbers showing undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following pricing slider
http://amirolahmad.github.io/bootstrap-pricing-slider/

I need to combine first three characters of a number in `update()` function to rearrange the number. So that I can create a new number. But I am in stack to retrieve these characters.

Here is the code -

```
$(".blinder_realstate #slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    value: 1,
    min: 40000,
    max: 1400000,
    step: 10000,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        update(1, ui.value);
    }
});


update();

//changed. now with parameter
function update(slider, val) {
    //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
    var $amount = slider == 1 ? val : $(".blinder_realstate #amount").val();
    var $duration = slider == 2 ? val : $(".blinder_realstate #duration").val();

    if($amount > 1000000){
        alert($amount);
        var first_char = $amount[0];
        alert(first_char);
        var second_char = $amount[1];
        var third_char = $amount[2];

        var first_elem = first_char + second_char;
        var second_elem = second_char + third_char;

        if(second_elem >= 10){
            second_elem = 0;
        }

        var number_format = first_elem+''+second_elem+'00000';
        $amount = parseInt(number_format);
    }


    $total = ($amount * 1.8) / 100;
    $new_total = formatNumber($total - 395);
    $(".blinder_realstate #amount").val('£' + $amount);
    $(".blinder_realstate #amount-label").text('£' + $new_total);
    $(".blinder_realstate #duration").val($duration);
    $(".blinder_realstate #duration-label").text($duration);
    $(".blinder_realstate #total").val($total);
    $(".blinder_realstate #total-label").text($total);

    $('.blinder_realstate #slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> £' + formatNumber($amount) + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
}

function formatNumber(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}
```

It shows alert of `alert($amount)` value but shows `undefined` in `alert(first_char)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable amount is of integer type , it is not an array ..
So it is not valid

```
var first_char = $amount[0];
```

First convert amount in string , furher in character array

```
var charArr=String($amount).split('');
var first_char=charArr[0];
//similary for others
```

**Suggestion**

Make sure what you are getting here , so change all to in one type

```
var $amount = slider == 1 ? val : $(".blinder_realstate #amount").val();
$amount=parseInt($amount);
```

Comment: You don't need to split the `string` to use `bracket notation` on it. And you could also cast a variable as a string with `variable = String(variable)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert amount to a string.

```
var $amount = 1234;
var $amountStr = $amount.toString();
var first_char = $amountStr[0];

alert(first_char);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MatsKruger/xxpzgg4L/)